# How to upload Cloud files into Python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I use to upload excel files into pandas dataframe 
pd.ExcelFile if the files are in my local drive
How can I do the same if I have an Excel file in Google Drive or Microsoft One Drive and I want to connect remotely?

Answer (score 1):

You can use read_csv() on a StringIO object:

```
from StringIO import StringIO  # moved to io in python3.

import requests
r = requests.get('Your google drive link')
data = r.content

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
```

Comment: I tried your idea but it did not work I am getting the following error "TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes" I also tried with BytesIO in case that the problem was there

Comment: Can i get access to the sample file and then i can try from my end?

Comment: sure, here is the link='https://thi-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mariano_scandizzo_spartners_me/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=1150c9140ba3a4b0fa65434d1258afffc&authkey=AYmfdKY5SM6CzgeWucV-ZX8'

Comment: Access to this link has been removed, Sorry

Comment: sorry for that , the following one should work https://thi-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mariano_scandizzo_spartners_me/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=1150c9140ba3a4b0fa65434d1258afffc&authkey=AYmfdKY5SM6CzgeWucV-ZX8&expiration=2017-07-31T03%3a00%3a00.000Z thank you for all your help

Comment: Is not working because the system can’t read the content, url is not an .xls file so you need to fix or use the microsoft api to connect and read the files.

Comment: Check my blog https://techpickup.wordpress.com/2017/07/04/reading-google-sheets-data-using-python/ , this will tell you how to fetch the data from google spreadsheet, let me know if it helps u